# Like we can use _partials in Sass is there something like that for javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I just want to keep all javascript separate but before to upload I want to combine into one.

Like Sass do with CSS

[image]

[image]

**I want to do same with Javascript files only.**

Comment: this post might help [combine multiple js files into one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877321/multiple-javascript-files-combine-into-one

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at using some of JavaScriptMVC's functionality for this. Most useful for you would probably be StealJS - http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!stealjs

Using StealJS, you can write code like the following, to ensure some JavaScript is loaded, then run the script body as a callback:

```
steal('myapp/tabs.js',
      'myapp/slider.js', 
      'myapp/style.css',function(){

   // tabs and slider have loaded 
   $('#tabs').tabs();
   $('#slider').slider()
})
```

Then include it in a page...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  steal('myapp/myapp.js')
</script>
```

or...

```
<script type='text/javascript'
    src='../steal/steal.js?myapp/myapp.js'>
</script>
```

Then build everything ready for production...

```
js steal/buildjs path/to/page.html -to myapp
```

You can take your pick of what of JavaScriptMVC's functionality to use (personally I only use the documentation generation framework at the moment, though time permitting will probably look to pick more up...) - if you're only using Steal for building, then the following might be useful - http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!steal.build.pluginify

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [Spockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to achieve this.

Sprockets was chosen as one of the tools for the Asset Pipeline in Rails 3.0. The Sprockets page on github states its purpose as follows

> Sprockets is a Ruby library for compiling and serving web assets. It
>   features declarative dependency management for JavaScript and CSS
>   assets, as well as a powerful preprocessor pipeline that allows you to
>   write assets in languages like CoffeeScript, Sass, SCSS and LESS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **[CofeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)** and it's compiler ([See the usage](http://coffeescript.org/#usage))

Comment: Is it not necessary to use coffee script style coding in that case?