# Single JS script or multiple scripts?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm using a single JS script for drawing 30-40 html canvases on a single page. The content of the canvases change with user input.
Does breaking the script into 5-10 separate scripts improve the loading time?

Comment: Take a look at the following question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398072/should-i-split-my-javascript-into-multiple-files

Comment: Will all of the scripts be used by every user? If so, then just include them in one file. It won't make a difference. What will have an impact though - as far as I'm aware - is multiple calls to a server for different files.