# What is the proper way to include modules in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using quite a bit of javascript in which it would be rather helpful if I could use global constants and a few methods that I use all over my web site.

Instead of having to copy and paste these into each js file, is there a way to include them?

like:

```
#include global.js

jsCode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple techniques for module architecture

- include multiple script tags and use namespaces to avoid global scope issues
- use asynchronous file loaders like [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
- use module packagers like [modul8](https://github.com/clux/modul8)

The latter techniques are probably overkill, you probally want a

`<script src="global.js" />`

in your html master page.

Comment: Hi, ok so if i include it in the  html page, then i can reference a function inside the global.js from within another js file as long as it is included after the global.js?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no *standard* JavaScript way to include one JavaScript file into another JavaScript file (I believe this is one of those lovely JavaScript's peculiarities.)

But, before you start to choose work-around, note that it's often considered a good practice to merge JavaScript files all over the project into a single big file (in short, this technique reduces number of HTTP requests and improves performance, for more explanations and caveats see [Merging multiple javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950441/merging-multiple-javascript-files#1950465).)