# combining multiple js files into 1 single file

Tags: jquery, jsmin

I am trying to combine all my js files into 1 js file.

Everything is working perfectly until I'm trying to copy and paste the content of the jQuery 2.0.2 file.

I can make it work via JSMin but I prefer not to use this method so I was wondering if there is any quick SIMPLE solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use PHP Minify. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490618/multiple-javascript-css-files-best-practices

Comment: Are you on Mac? CodeKit is a great piece of software to check for errors and auto minifiy

Comment: Hey Alex, Thanks for your quick answer.
 I am on PC... I was using PHP Minify and it's working but I do not want to rely on 3rd party external files. I want to make it as simple as possible...