# Where should I be putting css

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website, and the styles change frequently between pages. So what I have is images of pages that have the same header, same footer, and out-of-whack body styles. I started with the header and footer, and used a single css file that is linked in the header.

The problem is, as I do the pages, I have been adding css I need to the css page. I now have 1600 lines of css and I'm not done. I commented everything really well, but I have to use ctrl-f to find the element I need to change.

Now, I could separate them into different files and have a header with 10ish linked style sheets, but I didn't know if this was the "right" thing to do. Am I better off just having one large file? Is there a performance issue with multiple linked css files? Or is inline styling the better answer?

Comment: I typically separate CSS by feature...then in the build process you concat and minify all those related features to 1 file.

Comment: See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490618/multiple-javascript-css-files-best-practices) for best practices with multiple CSS files

Comment: That's helpful. Mostly I want to make sure the next person who looks at the website won't have trouble making changes.

Comment: note: the accepted answer in the linked post above only outlines one tool. Search for build tools (gulp for example) and let them concatenate your files for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separating the stylesheets is entirely acceptable, and up to you.  Anyhow, you can do one stylesheet for the base styles, and one stylesheeet for any custom sections if you want.

You wouldn't want to do one custom stylesheet for header, and one for footer, etc.., i dont think that's a good idea, separate them by content, not by html tags.

if you get a chance, post a site link so we can take a look at the styles.

how you would do this is just include each stylesheet from your main index file, or wherever your loading the files, like this..

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
</head>
```

EDIT:

i should mention, please note, the order you load them in is important if you accidentally, or purposely override any styles.
say for instance you have a body style on the first sheet loaded, theme.css in this case, then if you have a different body style in gallery.css it will override it.  so be careful not  to do any overrides unless you intend.

Overrides are a great way to have more control also, take for example if you include bootstrap.css first, you include your theme.css after, overriding any bootstrap styles that you want to customize for example.  you would leave the styles alone on bootstrap.css never touching them, then put a duplicate style name on your theme.css and change one or more of its properties to override it.  This is why its important to load them in order.  So pay attention to the order you load them in if you split your stuff up.

Its best to put your primary and most important style sheet first, then your override anything you need on a custom basis after.

Answer (score 2):

I've always opted for having a single file, but depending on the organization of your CSS, it might be easier to break it into multiple.  At the end of the day there is no one right answer.  It depends on the circumstances and developer's preference.  I would say that whatever you do, make it consistent.